# JS script only applied after window resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swipe, window-resize

I am using an external library - [SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com/) - for a touch picture slide, and it is only working when I resize my browser window.

I have my images in the Swipe Container like this inside the body:

```
<div id='mySwipe' style='max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto' class='swipe'>
<div class='swipe-wrap'>
<div>
    <img src="css/images/image4.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="css/images/image2.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="css/images/image3.jpg" width="100%" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And, I am loading the swipe script right at the end of the body to make sure the document is ready - as the library author suggested. The library is loaded inside the `<head>` container.

```
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
        startSlide : 1,
        auto : 3000,
        continuous : true
    });
</script>
```

I have tried to check if the document is ready with `$(document).ready(function() { }` but that solution did not work either.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? What do you mean by "...but that solution did not work either"?

Comment: @AlexW No there are no errors in the console. Also, I mean that adding the code inside the document ready function did not work, that the slider still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the widgets default example with just your minor tweaks specifically?

```
<script>
    var slider = Swipe( document.getElementById('mySwipe'), {
        startSlide: 1,
        auto: 3000,
        continuous: true,
        disableScroll: false,
        stopPropagation: false,
        callback: function(index, elem) {},
        transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
    } );
</script>
```